# Selenium Specflow Hooks to close driver after test run

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, hook, specflow

I currently have a very simple Selenium Specflow framework which open a Chrome or Firefox browser. I want to add an `AfterTestRun` hook to quit and dispose of the driver so that the browser closes correctly.

**LoginPage.cs:**

```
[Binding]
public class LoginPage
{
    private IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    [Given("I open a (.*) browser with a (.*) resolution (.*)")]
    public IWebDriver CreateBrowserInstance(Browser browser, BrowserResolution resolution, bool headless)
    {
        switch(browser)
        {
            case Browser.Chrome:
                Driver = StaticWebDriverFactory.GetChromeWebDriver(resolution, headless);
                return Driver;
            case Browser.Firefox:
                Driver = StaticWebDriverFactory.GetFirefoxWebDriver(resolution, headless);
                return Driver;
            default:
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException($"{browser} is not currently supported.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Hooks.cs**

```
[Binding]
public class Hooks
{
    private IWebDriver Driver { get; }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public void AfterTestRun()
    {
        Driver.Quit();
        Driver.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I don't have the Hooks file, the test will open the browser as expected. However we I add it in and run the test, the test is skipped. I am not sure where I am going wrong with the hooks.

**Edit:**

I tried to put the `[AfterScenario]` in the `LoginPage.cs` file and it worked as expected.

I am not sure why I cannot have my test hooks in a separate file as they will be used by all tests/pages. Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: In your LoginPage class you need to call hooks inside constructor.I can't see any constructor for LoginPage class.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure why I cannot have my test hooks in a separate file as
>   they will be used by all tests/pages. Am I looking at this the wrong
>   way?

You can have your test hooks in a separate file [That's the best practice] and also multiple times. The test runner will execute all the hooks methods.

**The binding methods for before/after feature and before/after test run events must be static**

Now in your case debug and check whether your `Driver` property is having the instance of webdriver which you want to close in aftertest run method.

By looking at your code it seems like `Driver` property in your Hooks class doesn't have the current instance of your webdriver.